# Autodesk Forge Viewer v7: MarkupsCore Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I couldn't find any documentation for **MarkupsCore** Extension for the **Viewer v7** from [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/).

Is there any reason or did I miss something?

I want to know can I refer to previous versions documentation even if I'm using the Viewer v7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a known documentation issue. You can use this one instead. It's the same for v7.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v4/reference/javascript/markupscore/

Our engineering team has a plan to provide better documentation in the future. Once we got updates from them, we will post an announcement for that. Please stay tuned with us. Cheers!